# Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification API not supported in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to certify my application but I get the following errors:
Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:

```
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification. Module=. File=X.Service.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification..ctor. Module=. File=X.Service.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification.put_SuppressPopup. Module=. File=X.Service.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager. Module=. File=X.Service.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier. Module=. File=X.Service.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent. Module=. File=X.Service.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotifier. Module=. File=X.Service.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotifier.Show. Module=. File=X.Service.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType. Module=. File=X.Service.dll.

Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Phone Store apps violates the Windows Phone Store certification requirements.
```

However if you check these msdn pages you can see that it is clearly supported in WP 8.1 Silverlight:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.notifications.aspx

`Minimum supported phone
    Windows Phone 8.1 [Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 and Windows Runtime apps]`

Anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the issue. It's in the WMAppManifest.xml, you have to select WNS if you want to use Windows.UI.Notifications otherwise you have the use ShellToast. Check this page out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642085%28v=vs.105%29.aspx