# type or namespace name 'ShellToast' could not be found in background Task

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I upgraded a windows phone 8 app to 8.1 silverlight. But while working with geofencing I wanted to show a toast. So I wrote this code

```
public sealed class Task : IBackgroundTask
    {
        static string TaskName = "GeofenceTask";
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            // Get the information of the geofence(s) that have been hit
            var reports = GeofenceMonitor.Current.ReadReports();
            var report = reports.FirstOrDefault(r => (r.Geofence.Id == "sample") && (r.NewState == GeofenceState.Entered));

            if (report == null) return;

            // Create a toast notification to show a geofence has been hit
            var toastXmlContent = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);

            var txtNodes = toastXmlContent.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            txtNodes[0].AppendChild(toastXmlContent.CreateTextNode("Geofence triggered toast!"));
            txtNodes[1].AppendChild(toastXmlContent.CreateTextNode(report.Geofence.Id));

            var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXmlContent);

            var toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();

            toastNotifier.Show(toast);
        }
}
```

But during certification it says

> This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification. Module=.
>   File=GeofenceTask.winmd.

After which I did some research and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230959/windows-ui-notifications-toastnotification-api-not-supported-in-windows-phone-si) which says

> you have to select WNS if you want to use Windows.UI.Notifications
>   otherwise you have the use ShellToast

So I was using MPN because Azure mobile service does not support WNS for WP8.1 silverlight apps.

> Notification Hubs Windows Phone SDK does not support using WNS with
>   Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight apps.

[Source](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-phone-get-started/)

So I thought I should use ShellToast in that case. But now I reached the real dead end. ShellToast is not supported in Windows runtime component projects. I dont have the right reference needed. i.e., Microsoft.Phone.Shell. If I add

```
Using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
```

'Phone' shows with red underline. What should I do?

**Update:**

I tried to add the Microsoft.phone.dll from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0

but I got an error where the ToastShell was defined which says:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidProgramException' occurred in
>   GeofenceTask.winmd but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid
>   program.

Answer (score 1):

So you need another assembly that contains the classes you need from the namespace `Microsoft.Phone.Shell`? I googled and found on msdn [ShellToast Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltoast%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) where an assembly is stated:

> Assembly:  Microsoft.Phone (in Microsoft.Phone.dll)

and

> **Version Information:**
>   Windows Phone OS
>   **Supported in: 8.1, 8.0, 7.1**

You have to add this dll to you project references. And it comes with WP OS so you can just reference it without having to bundle it with your app, so set `Copy Local: False`

[Edit]
Maybe you added the wrong assembly? The path you have posted in the comments to my answer seems wrong to me. Look for it in the following folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone\Microsoft.Phone.dll

Comment: I tried it and its not working. I added C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Designer\Microsoft.Phone.dll. There were no compilation errors but the toast just doesn't show up. I am currently unable to debug this background task using 'debug location' toolbar so don't really know what is happening but its not showing toast for sure.

Comment: @Rishabh876: I added a path to my answer, try to look for the dll in another folder.

Comment: That directory doesn't exist, in 'Silverlight' folder all I have is 'v5.0' that doesn't have a 'Profile' folder. I added one from a different folder. please check the error that I was getting

Comment: @Rishabh876: Well I can see you get the error: _Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program._ and in the path you stated I can't see `Silverlight`. I'm not an expert but that all screams **wrong framework** to me. You have to add a Silverlight dll, you cannot use the full .Net dll. Your folder path must contain Silverlight. Look into you folder **...\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v5.0** and try to find the dll in one of the subdirectories there

Comment: I was able to get C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone\Microsoft.Phone.dll but this dll does not have shelltoast class in Microsoft.Phone.Shell.